# Java String replacement with custom regex

Tags: java, regex, string, replace

I have a Java application which streams Twitter data.

Assuming that I have a `String text = tweet.getText()` variable.

In a text we can have one or more `@MentionedUser`. I'd like to delete not just the `@` but the username too.
How can I do this with `replaceAll` and without touching the rest of the string?

Thank you.

Comment: `text = text.replaceAll("@\\w+", "");`.

Comment: thank you. Could you explain me what do "\\w+" chars mean?

Comment: `\w` means word characters, `+` means a greedy quantifier matching 1 or more. [Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Comment: Abiut title: What would be non-custom regexp? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would like to use [`(^|\s)@\w+($|\s)`](https://regex101.com/r/US0XfC/1/) because you can get emails in your input like :

```
a @twitter username and a simple@email.com another @twitterUserName
```

So you can use :

```
String text = "a @twitter username and a simple@email.com another @twitterUserName";
text = text.replaceAll("(^|\\s)@\\w+($|\\s)", "$1$2");
// Output : a  username and a simple@email.com another
```

Details :

1. `(^|\s)` which match `^` start of string or `|` a space `\s`
2. `@\w+` match @ followed by one or more word characters which is equivalent to `[A-Za-z0-9_]`
3. `($|\s)`  which match `$` end of string or `|` a space `\s`

---

If you want to go deeper to specify the correct syntax of twitter usernames i read this [article here](https://support.twitter.com/articles/101299#) they mention some helpful information :

> - Your username cannot be longer than `15 characters`. Your name can be    longer (50 characters), but usernames are kept shorter for the
>     sake    of ease.
> - A username can only contain alphanumeric characters (letters `A-Z`, numbers `0-9`) with the exception of **underscores**, as noted above. ...

From this rules you use this regex as well :

```
(?i)(^|\s)@[a-z0-9_]{1,15}($|\s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative which does not produce doubled whitespaces and also does not capture emails:

```
String str = "a @twitter    @user     username and a john.doe@gmail.com another @twitterUserName @test jane@doe.com";
System.out.println(str.replaceAll("(?<=[^\\w])@[^@\\s]+(\\s+|$)", ""));
```

Output:

```
a username and a john.doe@gmail.com another jane@doe.com
```

Explanation of the parts of the actual regex expression `(?<=[^\w])@[^@\s]+(\s+|$)` :

1. *(?<=[^\w])@* - Try to find the '@' character and then look back to check that there is no regular character behind it (uses zero-width positive lookbehind).
2. *[^@\s]+* - Find something which is not an '@' or space character
3. *(\s+|$)* - Find multiple spaces or the end of the line